SSIS propagating columns backwards and through alternate multiast pipelines where they don't belong
Why does SSIS propagate columns BACKWARDS through the pipeline to the point where they don't yet exist, and then generate errors because of this?
My Data Flow looks as follows:

A: I have an OLE DB Source which grabs a set of columns I'll call "Foo"
C: I run this through a script which generates a new set of columns I'll call "Bar"
D: I sort columns "Bar".

I now add a multicast B, between A and C, to do something else with "Foo". This generates an error because "Bar" is undefined.

Of course it's undefined! It's from an alternate multicast branch! I never put it there! The worst part is if I click the X on all the Bar columns in this window, it deletes those columns from the entire rest of both pipelines, including for Script C which assigns their values.
What is causing SSIS to propagate these columns backwards, and down alternate multicast branches, then demand that I generate data that I never asked it for? How can I prevent this from happening?
